# How to get a single record to the template from model in emberjs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to ember js. I was trying to get a single record from my mongo db database but the query to server returns the full list view instead of a record.

templates/profile.hbs

```
{{#each item in model}}

  {{item.userName}}

{{/each}}
```

routes/profile.hbs

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
   model: function() {
        return this.store.find('user',{userName:'sanka'});
   }
});
```

Comment: Does `/user?userName=sanka` return a single record?

Comment: You should use this.store.query('user',{userName:'sanka'});

Comment: He should but this won't change the problem as server still returns the full list.

Answer (score 0):

New syntax for printing arrays is:

```
{{#each model as |item|}}

  {{item.userName}}

{{/each}}
```

Does your backend have a support for this kind of filter? Go check your network tab. Otherwise we won't be able to tell what your issue is. But it really looks as if you dont have support in your mongoDB. Because you're actually retrievering records, so it looks like the filter is "broken" or "non-existing"

[image]

To query for a single record that is not in an array you should be using

- findRecord(type,id)
- peekRecord(type, id)
- queryRecord(type, {query})

http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html